# TokenHelper Error with Connect-PnPOnline in powerShell Azure Function

Tags: azure, powershell, sharepoint, azure-functions, sharepoint-online

Currently, I'm Using the Connect-PnPOnline in a Powershell script:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -ClientId $tenant_client_id -ClientSecret $tenant_client_secret -Url $TenantUrl
```

When I run this code in the Windows PowerShell ISE, Works perfectly but if I try to run this in an Azure function this error appears:

```
ERROR: The type initializer for 'OfficeDevPnP.Core.Utilities.TokenHelper' threw an exception.

Exception             : 
    Type           : System.TypeInitializationException
    TypeName       : OfficeDevPnP.Core.Utilities.TokenHelper
    TargetSite     : 
        Name          : ProcessRecord
        DeclaringType : PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.ConnectOnline
        MemberType    : Method
        Module        : PnP.PowerShell.Online.Commands.dll
    StackTrace     : 
   at PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.ConnectOnline.ProcessRecord()
   at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.DoProcessRecord()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
    Message        : The type initializer for 'OfficeDevPnP.Core.Utilities.TokenHelper' threw an exception.
    Data           : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
    InnerException : 
        Type       : System.TypeLoadException
        Message    : Could not load type 'System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
        TypeName   : System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager
        TargetSite : Void .cctor()
        StackTrace : 
   at OfficeDevPnP.Core.Utilities.TokenHelper..cctor()
        Source     : OfficeDevPnP.Core
        HResult    : -2146233054
    Source         : PnP.PowerShell.Online.Commands
    HResult        : -2146233036
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-PnPOnline], TypeInitializationException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.TypeInitializationException,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.ConnectOnline
InvocationInfo        : 
    MyCommand        : Connect-PnPOnline
    ScriptLineNumber : 36
    OffsetInLine     : 1
    HistoryId        : 1
```

I need to use the Credential ID and The Client Secret to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to switch your Azure function to Version 1.0.

[image]

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions#languages) version 2 is .NET Core 2 and function app version 1.0 ~. That should be the cause why it prompt "Could not load type '[System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager?view=netframework-4.8)'.